# SQL query (if column contains certain value move it to another column)

Tags: sql

I'm relatively new to sql, so forgive me if my explanation isn't too clear. The column "invoice date week id" in the picture below shows in what week of a specific quarter a purchase was made. What I would like to do is this:

I would like to export all instances of W11,W12,and W13 into a new column called last3weeks. In other words, if the column contains week 11(W11), week 12(W12), and week 13(W13), then move it to a new created column called 'last3weeks'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dOT6.png)

Comment: Please write the db name version, and the query what result is your image table. And I think CASE statement you can transform a new column

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Sql IF THEN ELSE statement.
here's an example for that,

```
CREATE FUNCTION IncomeLevel ( monthly_value INT )
RETURNS varchar(20)

BEGIN

   DECLARE income_level varchar(20);

   IF monthly_value <= 4000 THEN
      SET income_level = 'Low Income';

   ELSEIF monthly_value > 4000 AND monthly_value <= 7000 THEN
      SET income_level = 'Avg Income';

   ELSE
      SET income_level = 'High Income';

   END IF;

   RETURN income_level;

END; //
```

you will just need to put on the condition you want ( W11 || W12 || W13 ) and set the value to a new column you can design by "as".